# Is there a way to bridge another wallet to my smart contract to retrieve the finds wrongfully sent there? Or selfdestruct it to get funds back?

Tags: remix, blockchain, smart-contract-wallets, scam

So my wallet was used to create a smart contract on the Remix ethereum website. The [code used to initiate this contract](https://pastebin.com/raw/0SsF8f2W) has malicious intent in which once I try to withdraw my tokens, they will be redirected to the hackers wallet. Is there anyway I can retrieve my tokens back to the creator wallet? Or self destruct the contract? Or bridge another wallet to get my money back? I put my savings in which was the first mistake. I can verify all proof that's needed; I haven't tried to withdraw yet so my tokens are technically still under the smart contract I created.

Comment: You can use the [contact us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, so that you can freely edit your post.

Comment: The link is down. In any case it is likely you have been scammed by following a youtube video about a front running bot written in solidity. There's no such thing as a bot written in solidity. The video and the comments are all fake. The people behind the scam change users and commenters all the time.