# Is there anyway to retrieve tokens sent to a smart contract?

Tags: metamask, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets, bytecode, scam

I used my wallet to create a smart contract for a trading bot. Unknowingly , the code for this smart contract was for malicious intent. Once i try to withdraw from the smart contract, my tokens will be redirected to a third party wallet, resulting in my funds being stolen. Is there any way for me to destroy the smart contract or do anything to redirect this scam and get my money back? Can really use some help, and it would be forever appreciated.i was hoping a self destruct call or a bridge from another network to the smart contract could hopefully avoid the withdraw scam..

Comment: I hope this is not a duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150148/is-there-a-way-to-bridge-another-wallet-to-my-smart-contract-to-retrieve-the-fin

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say without seeing the code. But, most likely the code is not trivial, so it's not really feasible for this forum to ask someone to analyze it.

Most likely the contract doesn't contain functionality to selfdestruct it, so that's not an option. Bridges won't probably help you in any way.

Basically you are bound by what functionality the contract supports. If it doesn't support something, you can't really do it.